# How to negate "regex" pattern for a character somewhere in the string using bash case statement

Tags: regex, bash

Here is a script to test my patterns

I know that these syntax as `/tmp/**` is not bash, they are just custom params which will be evaluated afterwards and therefore enclosed inside single quote to prevent bash expansion.

Each time the last test is failing and is interpreted as `file` and not `custom`
I'm unable to translate that `if string contains wildcard character somewhere in the string AND if not ending with * OR /` it is `file`

```
    #! /usr/bin/env bash

    #set -f # => nullglob 
    shopt -s extglob

    testcheck_params=()
    testcheck_vals=()

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/file')
    testcheck_vals+=("file")

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/file.tmp')
    testcheck_vals+=("file")

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/folder/')
    testcheck_vals+=("folder")

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/folder/*')
    testcheck_vals+=("all files & folders")

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/folder/**')
    testcheck_vals+=("all files no folder")

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/folder/*/')
    testcheck_vals+=("all folders no file")

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/folder/**/*')
    testcheck_vals+=("all files recursive")

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/folder/f*')
    testcheck_vals+=("custom")

    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/folder/*d*')
    testcheck_vals+=("custom")

 ## This one is failing interpreted as file and not custom
    testcheck_params+=('/tmp/folder/*.tmp')
    testcheck_vals+=("custom")

    for ((i=0 ; i<${#testcheck_params[@]}; i++))
    do

        echo "[ param: ${testcheck_params[$i]} ]"
        testcheck_param="${testcheck_params[$i]}"

        #case "$1" in
        case "$testcheck_param" in
            *[!\*]*[!/\*$])                     #*[!/\*$]|
                testcheck_val="file"
                echo "file"
            ;;
            *[!/][!\*][/$])             # => "/tmp/"
                testcheck_val="folder"
                echo  "folder"
            ;;
            *[!/\*][/][\*$])                    # => "/tmp/*"
                testcheck_val="all files & folders"
                echo "all files & folders"
            ;;
            *[!/\*][/][\*][\*$])                    # => "/tmp/**"
                testcheck_val="all files no folder"
                echo "all files no folder"
            ;;
            *[/][\*][/$])               # => "/tmp/*/"
                testcheck_val="all folders no file"
                echo "all folders no file"
            ;;
            *[/][\*][\*][/][\*$])               # => "/tmp/**/*"
                testcheck_val="all files recursive"
                echo "all files recursive"
            ;;
            *)
                testcheck_val="custom"
                echo "custom"
            ;;

        esac

    if [[ "${testcheck_vals[$i]}" == "${testcheck_val}" ]] ; then
        echo "TEST = PASSED"
    else
        echo "TEST = FAILED"
    fi

    done

    exit
```

I need to do this using case statement because it will be integrated in another script which is based on it.

I have read some examples on stackoverflow (but there no example witch negate explicitly character) and [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) but there is something that I can't understand.

Kind Regards

Comment: It is not clear. Are you looking to expand the glob patterns? or not? Because none of your patterns involving `*` will expand as expected i.e. `'/tmp/folder/**'` will be literal

Comment: Hello, no they are only 'custom' syntax params which are used inside config files and interpreted after using tools as find, cp, ln to perform actions .. using '/etc/apt/trusted.d/**'  will perform actions on each file inside  '/etc/apt/trusted.d' ...

Comment: Then perhaps you need to rephrase your question and provide a minimal non working part alone and ignore the other parts. As it stands now, it isn't clear what you are looking for

Comment: Sorry I'm not native english. `...=('/tmp/folder/*.tmp') ## This one is failing` and I have enclosed all params with single quotes to prevent bash expansion. my problem is a case "regex" pattern NOT matching `if string contains * somewhere`

Comment: You need something more sophisticated than an `extglob` Basic Regex switch. Since you are using Bash, profit from its Built-in Extended Regex `[[ "$testcheck_param" =~ \*.*[^*/]$ ]]` to define: `if string contains wildcard character somewhere in the string AND if not ending with * OR /`

Comment: @LéaGris, Hello if I understand well you advice me to replace case statement with `if .. then .. elif ... fi` statement which is more powerful with Extended Regex than the case one. Case statement does not support Extended Regex ?

Comment: @LéaGris tried your suggestion. it is working for the last check but first and second check do not work any more. I try to find a pattern which negate the existence of the `*` somewhere in the string using your example but failed.